# how can i find my generated files logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack, logstash-file

I'm beginner with ELK stack , so I configured logstash , and when I want to search with ElasticSearch I have no results , so I'm supposed to get a result , because I do my parse on grokdebug and it works very well .
I do my research as follows:

"http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.03.14/_search?q=*"

I wanted to know if I can see my logstash files generated and if it generated the results or not?

knowing that I tried searching elastic search on a JSON file and it works.

The problem is at logstash .

thanks

Comment: Here are some debugging ideas: http://svops.com/blog/debugging-your-elk-cluster/

Comment: Maybe you are searching the wrong index? List your indexes with http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash does not generate any file (except for its configuration).
To debug your logstash instance, you can :

- Use the --verbose flag and/or --debug
- Use the -l "file.log" to output logs in file.log (default to stdout)
- Use the stdout output plugin et see the results

Also, did you use the elasticsearch output plugin?